# String.Contains equivalent using Regex or something elegant

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have DateTime strings being passed in one of the following formats

- "2015/03/02T00:10:41+11:00"
- "2015-03-02T00:10:41Z"
- "2015-03-02T00:10:41"

I would like to find out if the string contains ('Z' or 'z') or ('+' or '-') to be able to distinguish between the various DateTime String formats.

I can use String.Contains and get the job done. I have something like this, it works but ... 
I am looking at an elegant way of doing it, preferably using Regex.

```
// dateTimeValue  = "2015-03-02T00:10:41Z";
// dateTimeValue  = "2015-03-02T00:10:41";
// dateTimeValue  = "2015/03/02T00:10:41+11:00";

if (dateTimeValue.IndexOf("Z", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
{
   // UTC ONLY DateTime
}
else if (dateTimeValue.Contains('+') || dateTime.Value.Contains('-')) 
{
  // User Time Only
}

(!Regex.IsMatch(dateTime.Value, @"^[\+\-]+$")) //doesn't work for the second conditional statement
```

Comment: I'd go with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you remus. I will go with your answer of DateTime.Parse rather than processing strings manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple `string.IndexOf()` with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` (to ignore case) to check if a character is present in the string.
Also, since the hyphen can be present in the date part, and date pattern will always contain "T", I can suggest the following tricky code:

```
var date_and_times = new[] { "2015-03-02T00:10:41Z", "2015-03-02T00:10:41", "2015/03/02T00:10:41+11:00" };
foreach (var date_time in date_and_times)
{
     bool? contains_Z = null;
     if (date_time.Split(new[] {'T'})[1].IndexOf("z", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
         contains_Z = true;
     else if (date_time.Split(new[] { 'T' })[1].Contains("+") || date_time.Split(new[] { 'T' })[1].Contains("-"))
         contains_Z = false;
     switch (contains_Z)
     {
         case true:
             // DateTime contains "Z" or "z"
             break;
         case false: 
             // DateTime contains "-" or "+"
             break;
         default:
             // DateTime has no "z", "Z", "+", or "-"
             break;
     }
 }
```

However, since you want to just parse datetime values, you should be using `DateTime.Parse()` or `DateTime.ParseExact()`.

```
var date_and_times = new[] { "2015-03-02T00:10:41Z", "2015-03-02T00:10:41", "2015/03/02T00:10:41+11:00" };

foreach (var date_time in date_and_times)
{
  var dt = DateTime.Parse(date_time);
}
```

Comment: how will you distinguish between option 1 and option 3

Comment: @InquisitiveLad: The question says "if the string contains *('Z' or 'z')* or *('+' or '-')*". Anyway, the question title is not about parsing date time values, but the question itself turned out to be. I will update the question just for the "art's sake".

Comment: I have accepted your code as the answer. I am sorry the question was misleading.